# Android: Better way of using Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I couldn't think of a better question title :(

In my application I need to have a questioner like thing with 10+ questions, 1 question each time.

What I did is:

1. Have 1 Activity say MainActivity, in its onCreate() programatically add a Fragment say Frag_1
2. In Frag_1 i have an Interface `onButtonClickedListener` with a method `onClicked` to get a call back to the Activity to know which option is clicked etc..,
3. Implemented the method onClicked of this Interface in my MainActivity and in that Method i changed the Fragment to Frag_2 (2nd question) and so on.

The problem is:

I ended up having 10 Fragments and my MainActivity implements 10 interfaces 1 each of these Fragments. In future I may have 30-40 question.

**Edit:**

Every question will not be similar. Answer options for questions are EditText/Spinner/RadioButtons etc.., so i cannot use the same Fragment and just change the Question and Answer options Text.

Is there a better and more efficient way to approach this

Thank You

Comment: Do all the queestions have similar structure? If they do you can probably get away with using a viewpager and a fragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: No. some will have options as radio buttons/spinner/editText

Comment: Has to say, you asked the question brilliantly.. But better add your reply to Marco in the question itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.
Make a more broad/generic interface for the MainActivity to implement.
Maybe something like that `public void fragClickCallback(int fragId, Bundle data);`

that way on you implementation you can make a `switch() case` to know which question is from and your bundle can pack different keys for different types of answers (int for radion button/spinners, String for open answer, etc).

And mare sure that on every fragment transaction you use `.replace(...)` to remove the fragment before.

**edit**

furthermore, there are some clever ways you can built your fragments to not have to create billions of them. How many different types of questions there can be? let's count:

- multiple choice (single answer) -> integer (index)
- multiple choice (multiple answers) -> integer (flags)
- Number input -> float/double
- Edit Text -> String
- Date Picker -> long (epoch)
- time picker -> 3 integers(?)

so we have 6 fragments and 6 ways of handling the `switch statement`, now it's just pass the right parameters to the fragments

**edit:**

```
  @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
       outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
   }
```

and then on your Fragment ActivityCreated()

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore last state for checked position.
        mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
    }
}
```

those code was copied from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html I suggest you further reading that page.
That example is restoring a cursor position, but you can use it to restore your previous user answers (text, integer, float, whatever).

Comment: So, how many questions might be there, I will have a maximum of 6 Fragments, and just change their Text/Options??

Comment: exactly. You can create a `Bundle` and pass it to the fragments as `setArguments(Bundle)` and inside the fragment you get it with `getArgument()`

Comment: I have a small problem here. Since user must be able to go back and check the previous question, For every FragmentReplace i gave addToBackStack. Previously it was working fine. But now after started to just change the Text and options, I cant have this feature :( . Because, the Text remains the same as the Text set to the Last Viewed Fragment. So, no other way than using Different Fragments now?

Comment: one word: `savedInstanceState`. I'll edit my answer, check it out.